# How do I disable the circular menus in 2.82 and get the 'classic' menus back?

Tags: interface

I've used Blender for many years. I sincerely think it's the best open source project after LInux distros.
I updated to 2.8x and I found myself completely lost, but I understand that things must change and I want to learn the new GUI.

Anyway I strongly disagree on building interfaces like this:

[image: new menu]

If I do not learn numeric shortcuts, I need to read in circle every time...
Any way to go back to the classic and stupid drop down menu???
Or, better, to back to the old interface???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circular menu shown in the question is an optional shortcut.

The exact same feature is available in a classic drop down menu, either at the top left-hand side of the screen:

[image]

or with a right-click:

[image]

Wouldn't one of these options work for you? You can just ignore the new 'posh' version of the menu, and even disable its keyboard shortcut in the keybindings settings.

Comment: Thank you! I will get used to this new look sooner or later...